# How would I calculate the frequency of the sound produced by a bowed glass plate?

Tags: acoustics, frequency

I'm working on a project that involves getting a note to sound from a glass plate by bowing its edge with a violin bow. I'm trying to work out exactly what frequency I'll get from a piece of glass of certain dimensions, but every equation I've come across so far results in at least one dimension having no effect on the pitch produced - something that testing has shown not to be the case, so I've clearly got the wrong equations.

The pieces I'm using are $300 \times 50 \times 2\,\mathrm{mm}$, and variations around that sort of scale. They are fixed at each short end.

So my question is: which equation should I use to calculate the frequency produced by a piece of glass of any given dimensions when excited by a violin bow?

Comment: Please improve your question a bit. Namely: which equations did you try? I would start with calculating eigenfrequencies (wave equation for 2D/3D rectangular solid object), obtaining pulse response and then convolve with the driving mechanism.

Comment: What data do you have (i.e. post it)? I'd also recommend trying to find the fundamental frequency for each sample by 'pinging' with a rubber hammer.  The physics of bowed stimulation is quite messy.